# Schedule update/delete/add operations do not persist when trying to save in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

This code allows the user to add, delete, or update a date. The problem is when the user exits the window, the changes are not saved/persisted.

```
public ActionResult Save(Event updatedEvent, FormCollection formData)
{
    var action = new DataAction(formData);
    var context = new DataClasses1DataContext();

    try
    {
        switch (action.Type)
        {
            case DataActionTypes.Insert:
                context.Events.InsertOnSubmit(updatedEvent);
                break;
            case DataActionTypes.Delete:
                updatedEvent = context.Events.SingleOrDefault(ev => ev.Id == updatedEvent.Id);
                 context.Events.DeleteOnSubmit(updatedEvent);
                 break;
            default:
                 updatedEvent = context.Events.SingleOrDefault(
                 ev => ev.Id == updatedEvent.Id);
                 UpdateModel(updatedEvent);
                 break;
        }
        context.SubmitChanges();
        action.TargetId = updatedEvent.Id;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        action.Type = DataActionTypes.Error;
    }
        return (new AjaxSaveResponse(action));
}
```

Comment: First of all, I would recommend to break this method in additional methods, keeping the single responsibility principal. So a recommendation is to break it into Insert, Update, Delete and call them respectively from your code.
Next, have you run a debugger on that? Have you replicated this behavior? What did you get? Is there any error message? If yes please post this as well.

Comment: Clarified title, rewrote message body for clarity and style, indented code consistently

Answer (score 0):

First use breakpoint for which data send your controller
after
Must end your save changed

```
public ActionResult  ....
db.SaveChange();
```

//

```
public async ....
await db.SaveChangeAsync();
```